# how can i change the data inside the snapshot on firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native

On my project, I create a function to get the data from firebase and then return it but I always get an empty array this my function below

```
export const pullDataFromFirebase = (collectionName, reducerName) => {
let data = []
    onSnapshot(collection(db, collectionName), (snapshot) => {
        snapshot.docs.map((doc)=>{
            data.push(doc.data())
        })
    })
return data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix the use of promises with Firestore realtime updates. Functions that return a promise (`async` function) are meant to return a single result asynchronously. `onSnapshot` does not return a promise. Instead, it invokes the provided callback whenever the results of the query change.

If you just want to get the data from the Firestore, you can do this instead:

```
export const pullDataFromFirebase = async (collectionName, reducerName) => {
  const q = query(collection(db, collectionName));
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
  const documents = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }));

  return documents;
}
```

to access it, you must call the async function and use the `.then` method. See code below:

```
pullDataFromFirebase(collectionName)
.then((data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

To listen to changes between snapshots, you can use the sample code from these [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots):

```
export const pullDataFromFirebase = async (collectionName, reducerName) => {
      onSnapshot(collection(db, collectionName), (snapshot) => {
        snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
          if (change.type === "added") {
              console.log("Added", change.doc.id, change.doc.data());
              //call a function.
          }
          if (change.type === "modified") {
              console.log("Modified", change.doc.id, change.doc.data());
              //call an function.
          }
          if (change.type === "removed") {
              console.log("Removed", change.doc.id, change.doc.data());
              //call a function
          }
        });
      });
}
```

You could also use `React Hooks`, if you prefer. By using `useState()` and `useEffect()`. See code below:

```
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  async function pullDataFromFirebase(collectionName, reducerName) {
    const colRef = query(collection(db, collectionName))
    onSnapshot(colRef, (snapshot) => {
      setData(snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
        doc.data()
      })))
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    pullDataFromFirebase();
  },[])
```

The code above will be able to set your document's data to the state and be able to use it on another function.

Comment: so if there is a change on the firestore like an update of TITLE the data that i have wont be updated. and also i tried using redux inside tried dispatching an action but it doen'st work

Comment: You have to deal accordingly with listening realtime updates. See [View changes between snapshots](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots). I'll update my answer.